# Recurrence relation involving the $\max$ function (reference request): $p_{n + 1} = p_{n} + \max\{r_{p_{n} - 1} - 1, r_{p_{n}}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

Consider two sequences $(p_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(r_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that they satisfy the following recurrence relation:
\begin{align*}
p_{n + 1} = p_{n} + \max\{r_{p_{n} - 1} - 1, r_{p_{n}}\}
\end{align*}

where $p_{0} := r_{0}$ and $r_{k} = 0$ for every $k < 0$, and $r_{n}\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ are IID random variables supposed to be known whose distribution is not specified.

I would like to know if it is possible to determine the expression for $p_{n}$ in terms of $(r_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

I do not need a full explanation (although a starting point would be appreciated). I would like to know if anyone could provide me any reference where I could find the corresponding theory related to the solution to this problem.

The same question has been asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444732/recurrence-relation-involving-the-max-function-reference-request-p-n-1).

Any suggestion (book, article, etc) is quite appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasKojar This is part from my research project where it is assumed that $(r_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are random variables supposed to be known.

Comment: @ThomasKojar The random variables do not have a particular distribution, but we can suppose they are uniformly distributed for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I'd break it into two problems, the first $p_{n+1} = p_n + \max\{a_n,b_n\}$ with $a_n,b_n$ uniform over $N-1, N$ respectively, and second $p_{n+1} = p_n + r_{p_n}$ with $r_k$ uniform over $N$. If you can solve these two, they can probably lead you closer to the answer.

Comment: also, do you have any specific questions about it? This appears to fall under "Random iterated functions" eg. https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/iterate.pdf "Iterated Random Functions".